# Named Entity Recognition from personal Gazetter using Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, named-entity-recognition

I try to do named entity recognition in python using NLTK.
I want to extract personal list of skills.
I have the list of skills and would like to search them in requisition and tag the skills.
I noticed that NLTK has NER tag for predefine tags like Person, Location etc.
Is there a external gazetter tagger in Python I can use?
any idea how to do it more sophisticated than search of terms ( sometimes multi words term )?

Thanks,
Assaf

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used NLTK enough recently, but if you have words that you know are skills, you don't need to do NER- just a text search.

Maybe use Lucene or some other search library to find the text, and then annotate it? That's a lot of work but if you are working with a lot of data that might be ok. Alternatively, you could hack together a regex search which will be slower but probably work ok for smaller amounts of data and will be much easier to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [RegexpTagger](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.tag.sequential.RegexpTagger-class.html) and eventually [RegexpParser](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.chunk.regexp.RegexpParser-class.html), I think that's exactly what you are looking for.

You can create your own POS tags, ie. map skills to a tag, and then easily define a grammar.

Some sample code for the tagger is [in this pdf](http://www.loria.fr/~gardent/applicationsTAL/slides/l5-nltk-tagging-2x2.pdf).